# how to get file name and directory from user through Gui

Tags: java

I want to get the file name and directory to save the file from user using Gui, like we use JFileChooser for selecting the file, please tell how I can do that???

Comment: Use a textfield an store the value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're really asking, but does this help?

```
public static File chooseDirectory(final Component parent, final String commitButtonText, final String commitTooltipString, final String chooserWindowTitle) {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int selection = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
    if (selection != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Ok, the user has selected a folder.
     */
    return new File(chooser.getCurrentDirectory(), chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) gives a pretty good demo of how to use fileChoosers. Here's the code featured at the top of the docs, adapted for your question (saving in particular)

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(); //Actually shows the chooser
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
   System.out.println("The path of this file is: " + 
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
   System.out.println("Writing...");
   try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"))
   {
     fw.write("yourfilename".toString());
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question. Getting the filename and directory can be done with this statement:

```
myTextField.setText(myFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

As for saving the file, just write the file to some given file name.

```
 try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFileChooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"))
 {
     fw.write("yourfilename".toString());
 }
```